# ThreeSixty Degree Image Slider Rotate from one index to other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, 360-degrees

```js
var threesixty = new ThreeSixty(document.getElementById('threesixty'), {
    image: [
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_1.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_2.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_3.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_4.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_5.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_6.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_7.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_8.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_9.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_10.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_11.jpg',  
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_12.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_13.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_14.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_15.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_16.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_17.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_18.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_19.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_20.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_21.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_22.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_23.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_24.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_25.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_26.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_27.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_28.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_29.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_30.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_31.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_32.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_33.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_34.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_35.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_36.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_37.jpg',
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_38.jpg',
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_39.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_40.jpg', 
       'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_41.jpg', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_42.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_43.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_44.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_45.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_46.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_47.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_48.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_49.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_50.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_51.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_52.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_53.jpg',
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_54.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_55.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_56.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_57.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_58.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_59.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_60.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_61.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_62.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_63.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_64.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_65.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_66.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_67.jpg', 
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_68.jpg', 
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_69.jpg', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_70.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_71.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_72.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_73.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_74.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_75.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_76.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_77.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_78.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_79.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_80.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_81.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_82.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_83.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_84.jpg',
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_85.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_86.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_87.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_88.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_89.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_90.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_91.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_92.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_93.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_94.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_95.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_96.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_97.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_98.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_99.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_100.jpg',
       'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_101.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_102.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_103.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_104.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_105.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_106.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_107.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_108.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_109.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_110.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_111.jpg',  
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_112.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_113.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_114.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_115.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_116.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_117.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_118.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_119.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_120.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_121.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_122.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_123.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_124.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_125.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_126.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_127.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_128.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_129.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_130.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_131.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_132.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_133.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_134.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_135.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_136.jpg',
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_137.jpg',
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_138.jpg',
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_139.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_140.jpg', 
       'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_141.jpg',   'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_142.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_143.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_144.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_145.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_146.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_147.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_148.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_149.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_150.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_151.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_152.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_153.jpg',
          'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_154.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_155.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_156.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_157.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_158.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_159.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_160.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_161.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_162.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_163.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_164.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_165.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_166.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_167.jpg',  
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_168.jpg',  
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_169.jpg',  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_170.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_171.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_172.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_173.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_174.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_175.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_176.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_177.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_178.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_179.jpg',    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider/master/img/threesixty_180.jpg'
        
    ],
  width: 1000,
  height: 500,
  speed: 100
});
 $("#services-menu li a").hover(function()
 {
   var $id=$(this).attr('id');     
   threesixty.goto($id);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mladenilic/threesixty.js/dist/threesixty.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="services-menu" id="services-menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="1" class="active">item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="36">item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="72">item3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="108">item4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="144">item5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="180">item6</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="threesixty"></div>
```

I am using [ThreeSixty.js](https://github.com/mladenilic/threesixty.js/blob/master/README.md) to rotate an image. When the hover happens on the links, the image automatically rotate to the index(id) of the link. When I used `threesixty.goto($id);` to go to the index of the image, image straightly rotate to that index. I was wondering is there any way I can slowly rotate from one index to other?

For example, if hover happens on `item2` link, image rotate the index from 1 to 36 (current index/id of the link/)

Comment: It seems possible but please remember this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't mean to write a code for me. I have checked the plugin documentation and couldn't find a way to rotate from one index to another. I am not sure how to add jquery rotate/animate if I can associate it in this plugin.

Comment: You are correct, there is no built-in method to do what you want. But a combination of `.goto()`, `.next()` should allow you to command ThreeSixty to progress from one index to another. You will write something like the internal, recursive `._loop()` method, using the `.index()` method to test when the animation has arrived at the target index, at which the recursion should cease. Give it a try. BTW, ThreeSixty is not a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Hi @Zendie, author of threesixty.js here. First of all, thank you for using it. :) @Roamer-1888 is 100% on point here, there's no built-in method to accomplish this, but it is doable. If you are up for it, I could help you with a PR that would add an option to `goto` method to loop to a given index.

Comment: @MladenIlić Thank you. I am still using threesixty.js. I am trying to achieve it.It would be helpful if we have an option for it.

Comment: Hi guys, I had a go at writing this and found it more practical to write an `.advanceBy(numberOfFrames)` method. This avoids the need for the end-programmer to bother with calculating the end-index (which is slightly tricky because of the circular nature of the data) - the method just uses `.next()` recursively, similar to `._loop()`. It arguably composes better as `playSequence(startFrame, numberOfFrames)` (looking after the initial `.goto()`).

Comment: Hi again, 
My attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/s02euct6/
Notes -
(1) Uses a partial emulation of ThreeSixty, not the real thing;
(2) `.playSequence(startIndex, numberOfFrames)` method is based on OP's requirement;
(3) `.playSequence(...)` returns Promise to allow the option of doing something when the play sequence completes;
(4) The Promise resolves with `this.index` at the end of the sequence, or rejects with an Error if the sequence is stopped before completion.
(5) Minimally tested;
(6) Feel free to raid for ideas.